# minus one error when trying to connect to database with Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect to a Postgres DB using Oracle SQL Developer. This is the datasource URL I see in an application which uses the DB:

```
jdbc:postgresql://10.11.12.13:5432/mydb?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&sslmode=require
```

I have the correct username and password but when I try to connect I get:

> Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: got minus one from a read call

I think this is because I don't have a `SID` or `Service name` populated. How can I find what these are?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is primarily intended for, well, Oracle. It's quite complicated to get it to work with Postgre**s**. But you need _at least_ install and register the JDBC driver in the Oracle SQL Developer options. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, I have that and can connect to other Postgres DB's.

Comment: The error message is a typical Oracle error message. So maybe that server isn't running Postgres at all

Comment: The mention of SID/service name suggests you've left connection type 'Basic' selected; is that the case for the other Postgres connections you have working, or are those 'Custom JDBC'?